# Why should std::string's back() return a reference to a char?

Tags: c++

The std::string's back() returns a reference to a char.  Why a ref?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/back/

```
      char& back();
const char& back() const;
```

Why not just drop the `&`?

Comment: If it weren't a reference, it wouldn't be "the back of the string", but "a value equal to the one at the back of the string".

Comment: Ok, I see the point for the non-const version where you may want to modify that char.  Is there any benefit to & on the  const version?

Comment: My original point stands. Maybe I want to take the address of that element and use that to base some logic on. Modifying an object is only one of many things you can do with an object. The `back` API doesn't care, it just gives you the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok, I see the point for the non-const version where you may want to modify that char. Is there any benefit to & on the const version?

`std::string` is an alias of `std::basic_string<char>`.

Whether you know it or not, you are asking about the return type of `std::basic_string<charT>::back()`.

`const charT& std::basic_string<charT>::back() const;` returns a reference because returning a reference is known to be efficient, while returning a copy of an arbitrary `charT` type is unknown.  It might be efficient, and it might not.

Answer (score 4):

A reference allows you to alter the value referred to. This follows the behaviour of other containers in the Standard Library.

Then the question becomes: why not return a reference?

Answer (score 3):

Because the `back()` function on standard containers gives you a reference to the last element, so that you can do things with that element.

`std::string` provides you with the same interface.

Why shouldn't it?